# mpgs Transaction: Pay.Tokenize payment process issues

Tags: mastercard

I'm integrating MPGS (Mastercard Payment Gateway Services). I want to use token to pay. But when I call the API Transaction "Pay", I get the wrong result. I want to know what went wrong. Thank you very much.

This is my payment process:

1. Use hosted checkout to complete the payment and save the `sessionid` of successful payment
2. Use the `sessionid` obtained in the first step to get the token and store the token

Reference API： `POST /api/rest/version/62/merchant/{merchantId}/token`

RequestBody:

```json
    {
    "session": {
        "id": "SESSION0002130457496K8245619M90"
    }
```

3. Create session and obtain the `sessionid` and `OrderID`.
   Reference API： [Session: Create Checkout Session](https://ap-gateway.mastercard.com/api/documentation/apiDocumentation/rest-json/version/62/operation/Session%3A%20Create%20Checkout%20Session.html?locale=zh_CN)
4. Use Transaction: Pay to start payment

Reference API：[Transaction: Pay](https://ap-gateway.mastercard.com/api/documentation/apiDocumentation/rest-json/version/62/operation/Transaction%3A%20%20Pay.html?locale=zh_CN)

RequestBody:

```json
    {
    "apiOperation": "PAY",
    "order": {
        "amount": 10.55,
        "currency": "HKD"
    },
    "session": {
        "id": "SESSION0002249161342J64341132I3"
    },
    "sourceOfFunds": {
        "token": "5123456709720008",
        "type": "SCHEME_TOKEN",
        "provided": {
            "card": {
                "expiry": {
                    "month": "01",
                    "year": "39"
                },       
                "storedOnFile": "TO_BE_STORED"
            }
        }
    },
    "transaction": {
        "source": "INTERNET"
    },
    "agreement": {
        "id": "m599944354",
        "type": "UNSCHEDULED"
    }
}
```

Response

```json
    {
    "agreement": {
        "id": "m599944354",
        "type": "UNSCHEDULED"
    },
    "gatewayEntryPoint": "WEB_SERVICES_API",
    "merchant": "myMerchantId",
    "order": {
        "amount": 10.55,
        "authenticationStatus": "AUTHENTICATION_NOT_IN_EFFECT",
        "chargeback": {
            "amount": 0,
            "currency": "HKD"
        },
        "creationTime": "2022-05-19T08:08:43.740Z",
        "currency": "HKD",
        "id": "2022051520752464800620225416016",
        "lastUpdatedTime": "2022-05-19T08:08:43.754Z",
        "merchantAmount": 10.55,
        "merchantCategoryCode": "4812",
        "merchantCurrency": "HKD",
        "status": "FAILED",
        "totalAuthorizedAmount": 0,
        "totalCapturedAmount": 0,
        "totalDisbursedAmount": 0,
        "totalRefundedAmount": 0
    },
    "response": {
        "gatewayCode": "BLOCKED"
    },
    "result": "FAILURE",
    "risk": {
        "response": {
            "gatewayCode": "REJECTED",
            "review": {
                "decision": "NOT_REQUIRED"
            },
            "rule": [
                {
                    "data": "NO_LIABILITY_SHIFT",
                    "name": "MSO_3D_SECURE",
                    "recommendation": "REJECT",
                    "type": "MSO_RULE"
                },
                {
                    "data": "512345",
                    "name": "MSO_BIN_RANGE",
                    "recommendation": "NO_ACTION",
                    "type": "MSO_RULE"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "sourceOfFunds": {
        "provided": {
            "card": {
                "brand": "MASTERCARD",
                "expiry": {
                    "month": "1",
                    "year": "39"
                },
                "fundingMethod": "CREDIT",
                "number": "512345xxxxxx0008",
                "scheme": "MASTERCARD",
                "storedOnFile": "TO_BE_STORED"
            }
        },
        "token": "5123456709720008",
        "type": "CARD"
    },
    "timeOfLastUpdate": "2022-05-19T08:08:43.754Z",
    "timeOfRecord": "2022-05-19T08:08:43.754Z",
    "transaction": {
        "acquirer": {
            "id": "Myid",
            "merchantId": "myMerchantId"
        },
        "amount": 10.55,
        "authenticationStatus": "AUTHENTICATION_NOT_IN_EFFECT",
        "currency": "HKD",
        "id": "tran-14",
        "source": "INTERNET",
        "stan": "0",
        "type": "PAYMENT"
    },
    "version": "62"
}
```

Problem points:

1. Is my method of obtaining token correct?
2. Whether the method of using "Transaction: Pay" is correct, and whether the parameters of request body are missing
3. Why is the `order.authenticationStatus="AUTHENTICATION_NOT_IN_EFFECT"` in the response in step 4? What "There is no authentication information associated with this transaction." means?

Comment: Hi, i have a question please. ```Use hosted checkout to complete the payment and save the sessionid of successful payment``` in the hosted checkout i added a payment of 1$, does this mean that 1$ is charged by user, so i need to issue refund? or do i still need to call the PAY request?

Answer (score 0):

You need to update CARD Details using SESSION UPDATE and then make a payment using PAY.
Ensure the 3DS scheme is verified before attempting to PAY.

Comment: After payment has been made, how do i show user in frontend that the payment was successful?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to provide card expiry details again in the API request body as it is already stored in the token.

Your transaction is getting BLOCKED because of Risk Rejection rule

```
"NO_LIABILITY_SHIFT"
   "rule": [
             {
                "data": "**NO_LIABILITY_SHIFT**",
                "name": "MSO_3D_SECURE",
                "recommendation": "**REJECT**",
                "type": "MSO_RULE"
             }
     ]
```

The "NO_LIABILITY_SHIFT" rule is triggered when in the Merchant Admin Portal -> Transaction Filtering -> 3-D Secure Rules ->No Liability Shift -> "Reject" [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITySA.png) and you are trying to perform Pay operation without 3DS authentication as otherwise in case of fraud or chargeback the liability will be on the merchant and acquirer side.

You need to perform EMV 3DS authentication before Pay operation. https://eu-gateway.mastercard.com/api/documentation/integrationGuidelines/supportedFeatures/pickAdditionalFunctionality/authentication/3DS/3DSecureAuthentication.html?locale=en_US

Comment: @Sydney_dev I'm getting the same thing and sending the pre authenticated 3ds data on the request, as a matter of fact getting  "authenticationStatus": "AUTHENTICATION_SUCCESSFUL" but still getting "data": "NO_LIABILITY_SHIFT". Do you know what else could be causing it?